# How can I make a two-column layout with drop-caps responsive without scrollbars?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am learning the basics of html and css, and am trying to build my own blog from scratch, coding it all from the ground up, because that's the only way I'll really learn.  I want it to be responsive to different screen widths, so I am using the bootstrap grid, but building my own custom components because the bootstrap ones seem a bit too cookie-cutter.  Specifically, what I am having a hard time with is a single DIV element at the top of the page, where I want to contain my most recent blog post.  It contains a floated image, and two columns of text.  I have placed everything within rows in the grid, and what I am expecting is this: When someone begins minimizing the screen, or when a smaller device is used to view the site, I want the words to just realign to whatever screen size they have, and I do not want the scrollbars to appear.  Is there a way this can be done.  I have included the code below, (all of it), but the relevant DIV is posted first there at the top, and a picture of what it looks like at full screen size, and also one where the window is reduced in size.

Full size:
[image]

Resized screen:
[image]

Here is the DIV, and the relevant CSS.  Just in case I don't understand what might be relevant, the entire code is at the very bottom.  Thank you for any time taken to help me.  There are problems with positioning at the top, too, but I think I can figure that out, or I'll have to make that another question.  Thanks again.

DIV Element HTML:

```
<!--First Blog Post-->
<div class="row" id="row1">
    <div class="col" id="row1_col1">
    <!--Let's make our own version of card-->
        <div class="ourCard" id="fbPost">   
                <div id="holdHeader"><span id="badgePin" class="badge badge-primary">Featured</span><h3 id="titleTop">Historical Oncology</h3></div>
            <span id="postDate"><b>Posted On:</b>  <em>June 23, 2021</em></span>
            
            <hr id="blogOne_hr">
                <div id="holder">
                    
                    <img src="Images/473a9b83088edfa35bdba1b7691056ad.jpg" alt="..." class="cornImg" id="cornImg1">
                    
                        <div id="txtCol1" class="txtCol"><span id="dCap">T</span><p class="pInd">hThis is just a bunch of really stupid placeholder text that I have written out because there is no lorem ipsum anywhere to be found.  Anywys, I just need a bunch of text that I can copy and copy and copy and make sure it has no obsenities or anything stupid, so that blah blah blah blag andl asd frls al this is dumb why cant there be an option to throw placeholder </p>
                <p class="pInd">This is just a bunch of really stupid placeholder text that I have written out because there is no lorem ipsum anywhere to be found.  Anywys, I just need a bunch of text that I can copy and copy and copy and make sure it has no obsenities or anything stupid, so that blah blah blah blag andl asd frls al this is dumb why cant there be an option to throw placeholder </p>
                 <p class="pInd">This is just a bunch of really stupid placeholder text that I have written out because there is no lorem ipsum anywhere to be found.  Anywys, I just need a bunch of text that I can copy and copy </p></div>
                
                    
            </div>
        
            <p id="txtCol2" class="txtCol">Second column is just a bunch of really stupid placeholder text that I have written out because there is no lorem ipsum anywhere to be found.  Anywys, I just need a bunch of text that I can copy and copy and copy and make sure it has no obsenities or anything stupid, so that blah blah blah blag andl asd frls al this is dumb why cant there be an option to throw placeholder text stupid stupid sThis is just a bunch of really stupid placeholder text that I have written out because there is no lorem ipsum anywhere to be found.  Anywys, I just need a bunch of text that I can copy and copy and copy and make sure it has no obsenities or anything stupid, so that blah blah blah blag andl asd frls al this is dumb why cant there be an option to throw placeholder text stupid stupid std copy and make sure it has no obsenities or anything stupid, so that blah blah blah blag andl placeholder text stupid stupid std copy and make sure it has no obsenities or anything stupid, so that blah blah blah blag andl  </p>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="blogButton" id="fBlgBtn">Read More</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

/*IDs*/

#cornImg1 {
    width:120px;
    height:132px;
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    shape-outside:circle();
    margin-top:24px;
    border: 2px solid blue;
    border-radius:75%;
}
#txtCol1 {
    
}
#postDate {
    position:absolute;
    top:53px;
    right:125px;
    font-size:12px;
}
#txtCol2 {
    float:right;
    margin-left:15px;
    text-indent:3em;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}
#holdHeader {
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:Lavender;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    flex-wrap:no-wrap;
}
#badgePin {
    height:60%;
    width:65px;
    margin-left:60px;
    margin-top:10px;
}

#titleTop {
    position:absolute;
    left:41%;
    margin-bottom:3px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:'Lobster', cursive;
    font-size:30px;
}
#dCap {
    
  float: left;
  line-height: 85%;
  width: .7em;
  font-size: 400%;
  font-family: georgia;
}
#fBlgBtn {
    position:relative;
    left:1026px;
    bottom:40px;
    color:red;
}
#topBanner {
    width:100% !important;
    height:123px;
    background:black;
    
}
#fbPost {
    border: 2px solid blue;
    width:90%;
    height:355px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto;
    overflow:auto;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}
#blogOne_hr {
    position:absolute;
    top:58px;
    color:Lavender;
    width:1110px;
    height:3px;
    display:inline;
}
#secHolder {
    display:inline;
}
#holder {
    margin-right:15px;
    margin-left:15px;
    display:inline;
}
/*CLASSES*/
.techImg {
    width:75px !important;
    height:100px !important;
    border: 1px blue;
}

.txtCol {
    width:500px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:1.3em;
    letter-spacing:.13em;
    text-align:justify;
    margin-bottom:3px;
    margin-left:15px;
    margin-top:24px;
    
    
}
/*

font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Viaoda Libre', cursive; */
.pInd {
    display:inline;
    text-indent:3em;
}
.blogButton {
    
    background-color:Thistle;
    color:black;
    padding-top:1px;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    padding-bottom:1px;
    border-radius:25px;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:500;
}
```

Here is the entire HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Practicing with Div</title>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/endling_index.css">
    
     <!-- Add icon library -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
     <!-- Add icon library -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!--Include google fonts-->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lobster&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cabin&family=Lato&family=Lobster&family=Montserrat&family=Open+Sans&family=Playfair+Display:ital,wght@0,400;0,500;1,400&family=Roboto&family=Viaoda+Libre&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="javascript/divPlay.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo01">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">About</a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Philosphy <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Spiritualism</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Social Change</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Technology</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Projects</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>


    <div class="container-fluid">

    <!--Zeroth Row Banner Image-->
    <div class="row" id="row0">
        <div class="col" id="row0_col1">
            <img class="banPics" id="topBanner" alt="There will always be something to read here..." src="Images/bannerPlaceholder.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--First Blog Post-->
<div class="row" id="row1">
    <div class="col" id="row1_col1">
    <!--Let's make our own version of card-->
        <div class="ourCard" id="fbPost">   
                <div id="holdHeader"><span id="badgePin" class="badge badge-primary">Featured</span><h3 id="titleTop">Historical Oncology</h3></div>
            <span id="postDate"><b>Posted On:</b>  <em>June 23, 2021</em></span>
            
            <hr id="blogOne_hr">
                <div id="holder">
                    
                    <img src="Images/473a9b83088edfa35bdba1b7691056ad.jpg" alt="..." class="cornImg" id="cornImg1">
                    
                        <div id="txtCol1" class="txtCol"><span id="dCap">T</span><p class="pInd">hThis is just a bunch of really stupid placeholder text that I have written out because there is no lorem ipsum anywhere to be found.  Anywys, I just need a bunch of text that I can copy and copy and copy and make sure it has no obsenities or anything stupid, so that blah blah blah blag andl asd frls al this is dumb why cant there be an option to throw placeholder </p>
                <p class="pInd">This is just a bunch of really stupid placeholder text that I have written out because there is no lorem ipsum anywhere to be found.  Anywys, I just need a bunch of text that I can copy and copy and copy and make sure it has no obsenities or anything stupid, so that blah blah blah blag andl asd frls al this is dumb why cant there be an option to throw placeholder </p>
                 <p class="pInd">This is just a bunch of really stupid placeholder text that I have written out because there is no lorem ipsum anywhere to be found.  Anywys, I just need a bunch of text that I can copy and copy </p></div>
                
                    
            </div>
        
            <p id="txtCol2" class="txtCol">Second column is just a bunch of really stupid placeholder text that I have written out because there is no lorem ipsum anywhere to be found.  Anywys, I just need a bunch of text that I can copy and copy and copy and make sure it has no obsenities or anything stupid, so that blah blah blah blag andl asd frls al this is dumb why cant there be an option to throw placeholder text stupid stupid sThis is just a bunch of really stupid placeholder text that I have written out because there is no lorem ipsum anywhere to be found.  Anywys, I just need a bunch of text that I can copy and copy and copy and make sure it has no obsenities or anything stupid, so that blah blah blah blag andl asd frls al this is dumb why cant there be an option to throw placeholder text stupid stupid std copy and make sure it has no obsenities or anything stupid, so that blah blah blah blag andl placeholder text stupid stupid std copy and make sure it has no obsenities or anything stupid, so that blah blah blah blag andl  </p>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="blogButton" id="fBlgBtn">Read More</a>
    </div>
</div>
    <!--Most recent blogpost-->
<div class="row" id="row2">
    <div class="col" id="row2_col1">
        <!--Custom div?-->
        <!--Let's make our own version of card-->
        <div class="ourCard" id="fbPost">   
                <div id="holdHeader"><h3 id="titleTop">The Holy Saucer</h3></div>
            <span id="postDate"><b>Posted On:</b>  <em>June 23, 2021</em></span>
            
            <hr id="blogOne_hr">
                <div id="holder">
                    
                    <img src="Images/473a9b83088edfa35bdba1b7691056ad.jpg" alt="..." class="cornImg" id="cornImg1">
                    
                        <div id="txtCol1" class="txtCol"><span id="dCap">T</span><p class="pInd">This is just a bunch of really stupid placeholder text that I have written out because there is no lorem ipsum anywhere to be found.  Anywys, I just need a bunch of text that I can copy and copy and copy and make sure it has no obsenities or anything stupid, so that blah blah blah blag andl asd frls al this is dumb why cant there be an option to throw placeholder </p>
                <p class="pInd"> This is just a bunch of really stupid placeholder text that I have written out because there is no lorem ipsum anywhere to be found.  Anywys, I just need a bunch of text that I can copy and copy and copy and make sure it has no obsenities or anything stupid, so that blah blah blah blag andl asd frls al this is dumb why cant there be an option to throw placeholder </p>
                 <p class="pInd">This is just a bunch of really stupid placeholder text that I have written out because there is no lorem ipsum anywhere to be found.  Anywys, I just need a bunch of text that I can copy and copy and copy and make sure it has no obsenities or anything stupid, so that blah blah blah blag andl asd frls al this is dumb why cant there be an option to throw placeholder</p></div>
                
                    
            </div>
        
            <p id="txtCol2" class="txtCol">This is just a bunch of really stupid placeholder text that I have written out because there is no lorem ipsum anywhere to be found.  Anywys, I just need a bunch of text that I can copy and copy and copy and make sure it has no obsenities or anything stupid, so that blah blah blah blag andl asd frls al this is dumb why cant there be an option to throw placeholder text stupid stupid sThis is just a bunch of really stupid placeholder text that I have written out because there is no lorem ipsum anywhere to be found.  Anywys, I just need a bunch of text that I can copy and copy and copy and make sure it has no obsenities or anything stupid, so that blah blah blah blag andl asd frls al this is dumb why cant there be an option to throw placeholder text stupid stupid std copy and make sure it has no obsenities frls al this is dumb why cant there be an option to throw placeholder text stupid stupid std copy and make sure it has no obsenitiesfrls al this is dumb why cant there be an option to throw placeholder text stupid stupid std copy and make sure it has no obsenities </p>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="blogButton" id="fBlgBtn">Read More</a>
        
    </div>
</div>
    <!--Second most recent blogpost-->
<div class="row" id="row3">
    <div class="col" id="row3_col1">
    <!--Let's make our own version of card-->
    <div class="ourCard" id="fbPost">   
                <div id="holdHeader"><h3 id="titleTop">Transcendant Troubles</h3></div>
            <span id="postDate"><b>Posted On:</b>  <em>June 23, 2021</em></span>
            
            <hr id="blogOne_hr">
                <div id="holder">
                    
                    <img src="Images/473a9b83088edfa35bdba1b7691056ad.jpg" alt="..." class="cornImg" id="cornImg1">
                    
                        <div id="txtCol1" class="txtCol"><span id="dCap">T</span><p class="pInd">This is just a bunch of really stupid placeholder text that I have written out because there is no lorem ipsum anywhere to be found.  Anywys, I just need a bunch of text that I can copy and copy and copy and make sure it has no obsenities or anything stupid, so that blah blah blah blag andl asd frls al this is dumb why cant there be an option to throw placeholder </p>
                <p class="pInd"> This is just a bunch of really stupid placeholder text that I have written out because there is no lorem ipsum anywhere to be found.  Anywys, I just need a bunch of text that I can copy and copy and copy and make sure it has no obsenities or anything stupid, so that blah blah blah blag andl asd frls al this is dumb why cant there be an option to throw placeholder </p>
                 <p class="pInd">This is just a bunch of really stupid placeholder text that I have written out because there is no lorem ipsum anywhere to be found.  Anywys, I just need a bunch of text that I can copy and copy and copy and make sure it has no obsenities or anything stupid, so that blah blah blah blag andl </p></div>
                
                    
            </div>
        
            <p id="txtCol2" class="txtCol">This is just a bunch of really stupid placeholder text that I have written out because there is no lorem ipsum anywhere to be found.  Anywys, I just need a bunch of text that I can copy and copy and copy and make sure it has no obsenities or anything stupid, so that blah blah blah blag andl asd frls al this is dumb why cant there be an option to throw placeholderThis is just a bunch of really stupid placeholder text that I have written out because there is no lorem ipsum anywhere to be found.  Anywys, I just need a bunch of text that I can copy and copy and copy and make sure it has no obsenities or anything stupid, so that blah blah blah blag andl asd frls al this is dumb why cant there be an option to throw placeholderThis is just a bunch of really stupid placeholder text that I have written out because there is no lorem ipsum anywhere to be found.  Anywys, I just need a bunch of text that I can copy and copy and copy and make sure it has no obsenities or anything stupid, so that blah blah blah blag andl asd frls al this is dumb why cant there be an option to throw placeholde of tex</p>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="blogButton" id="fBlgBtn">Read More</a>
    
    </div>
</div>
    <!--Third most recent blogpost-->
<div class="row" id="row4">
    <div class="col" id="row4_col1">
    </div>
</div>
    <!--Horizontal Rule-->
<div class="row" id="row5">
</div>
    <!--Technological projects-->
<div class="row" id="row6">

    <div class="col" id="row5_col1">
        <div class="card-deck">
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="Images/473a9b83088edfa35bdba1b7691056ad.jpg" style="width:25%;height:25%;" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-header">Take Your Chains Back</div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="Images/473a9b83088edfa35bdba1b7691056ad.jpg" style="width:25%;height:25%;" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-header">Project One</div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="Images/473a9b83088edfa35bdba1b7691056ad.jpg"  style="width:25%;height:25%;" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-header">Just A Chip off the Block</div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Is there even any point to this?  Why don't I just make my own stuff.  All the bootstrap stuff looks the same, boring boring boring borin gobring obierteriterotje</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    </div>
    
    

</div>
    
<div class="row" id="row7">
    <br>
    <hr>
    <br>
</div>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good for you for trying to code a project like this from scratch! That's how I learn best too.

You're getting scrollbars because you're setting the height of the div in your `#fbPost` instead of letting it be determined by the content, and then you also set `overflow: auto`, which tells the browser to show a scrollbar if the content of a container overflows the container, and to hide the scrollbar if it doesn't. You can read more about that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

Also, as a best practice, an `id` is meant to be unique. So there should only be one thing in your html with `id="fbPost"`, you shouldn't put that on each of your sections. It's better to use classes like your `ourCard` class to style multiple elements.

In terms of how to make the content two columns, you can just use the [`column-count` css property](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css3_pr_column-count.asp).

I also recommend looking into and learning [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) for layouts instead of using floats (except you are using floats correctly for your image - that is exactly the use case floats were designed for. You just don't want to use it for columns and general layout).

Here's a very basic JSFiddle showing what I'm talking about: https://jsfiddle.net/karlynelson/vd7zq8h4/29/

You can use media queries to make it go down to one column of text at a certain point, or [use fancy css grid min-max and auto-fill to do it automatically](https://css-tricks.com/intrinsically-responsive-css-grid-with-minmax-and-min/).

Comment: Thank you for the very helpful info!  Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Glad I could help! Good luck with your blog!

Comment: Also, if you get to point where you don't want to hand code every blog post, but would like a way to use templates, I recommend using a static site generator. They're built to solve exactly that problem. My favorite is [Eleventy](https://www.11ty.dev/) but there are lots of others like [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/) and [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/).  [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/) is another one, but it uses React and might be a bit overkill, especially if you want to focus on html and css fundamentals first